# Did Harry make an Unbreakable Vow?

Tags: harry-potter, unbreakable-vow

I saw a question about [how the piece of Voldemort's soul would be affected if Harry broke the Unbreakable Vow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14519/60757) but it doesn't say what the Unbreakable Vow in question was.

I can't remember or find anything about Harry making one, so did he?

I have seen some speculation on having to make them for the Triwizard Tournament but as far as I am aware, this is untrue. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: No, he did not. Can you provide a reference for where you saw this?

Comment: @Adamant http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14519/60757

Answer (score 3):

There's only one instance in the Harry Potter books (and films) where an [unbreakable vow](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unbreakable_Vow) is made, that between Narcissa Malfoy and Severus Snape in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.

Harry doesn't ever make the vow, although he and Ron do discuss it.

> **Ron Weasley:** *"An Unbreakable Vow? Nah, he can't have...Are you sure?"*
>
> **Harry Potter:** *"Yes, I'm sure. What happens if you break it?"*
>
> **Ron Weasley:** *"You die."*

---

The question you've referenced is more of a "*what if*" style of question, speculating about the likely effects if Harry (a sorta horcrux) had broken an unbreakable vow, **rather than an actual instance from the films or books.**