# Is Harry only protected from Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Does the protection Lily made on Harry apply only from Voldemort? Is there any proof from the books?

Comment: Sorry about the false duplicate closure - this question is of course completely different from the one that was [originally linked as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22414/does-lily-potters-sacrifice-make-harry-and-voldemort-immortal?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, more-or-less the same question *has* been asked here before; I've now changed the link to point to the correct duplicate target.

Answer (score -2):

Yes; Harry is harmed on multiple occasions through the series by dark magic by the Death Eaters.

Comment: That doesn't matter as it only protects you from dying: Voldemort does crucio on Harry

Comment: Hmm, yeah, but the spell was sort of messed up by then; Voldemort was protected by it too. If he wasn't, he probably wouldn't have been able to do that.