# Was Harry a very powerful wizard when he casts the patronus charm at the dementors?

Tags: harry-potter, powers, wizards, dementors, patronus-charm

I was just watching Harry Potter "Prisoner of Azkaban". Just before the scene where Harry casts the patronus spell to get rid of the Dementors, Hermione says:

> Only a really powerful wizard could have conjured it.

I know the scene is a little bit different from the book where Hermione isn't with Harry at that point, but either way the question is the same.

At that point was Harry a really powerful wizard?

What does *"really powerful wizard"* mean?

Could the part of Voldemort inside of Harry have enhanced Harry's powers to help him cast the patronus charm even though Voldemort himself doesn't cast that particular spell?

Comment: I'd blame it on lots practice.

Comment: Really, I think it was both. We know that he gained some things like being able to speak Parsaltounge (sp), so why not help Harry in other ways as well. The Patronous was just a realization for Harry. Once he understood it wasn't his father which produced it and it was him, he had the confidence to use it. Harry *is* a powerful wizard ... he couldn't have been an Auror had he not been.

Comment: @Richard I know you're very dedicated to finding "Dupe's" to questions, but how exactly are those duplicates of what I'm asking? Clearly Snape, who is one of the greatest wizards of all time, points this out in the quote above. Harry fights very powerful wizards throughout the series and stands toe to toe with them or bests them. So the first dupe is an obvious question and mine is an answer to that question if anything and not a "dupe." The second "dupe" is completely unrelated. Not sure about your thinking there at all.

Comment: @JMFB - The second question is probably the closer. Slytherincess' [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37253/20774) specifically mentions which "powers" are transferred by Harry being a semi-Horcrux

Comment: @JMFB - The first question deals more with your title (e.g. ***is*** Harry a very powerful wizard, *per se*?)

Comment: @Richard I don't need a list of the obvious affected of being a horcrux. I know he can speak Parseltongue, that something weird happened between Harry and Voldemort when they fought in the graveyard, that Harry could hear Voldemort's thoughts, etc. I just want to know if Harry was great at this point in the series, why, and what that means exactly. The semi-horcrux may or may not be a part of this answer.

Comment: Patronus isn't **only** a question of power (Voldemort can't cast one. Neither can Hermione, at least on the level of Harry). It's a question of mental abilities. Harry's abnormal thing about protecting people is partly what goes into his.

Comment: @DVK I think your view of sets and subsets are a bit off. I never insinuated that ANYTHING is only a question of ANYTHING. Clearly a Patronus is very advanced magic, and takes a very powerful wizard to cast one, this is stated throughout the series multiple times. Regardless of whether additional abilities or knowledge are required, being powerful is a necessity to cast a patronus spell especially one of the magnitude Harry cast. If you disagree that significant magical power is necessary to cast one please refer me to a canon source and I'll update the question.

Comment: @DVK this is not a duplicate question. Richard made that suggestion in the comments section and I answered why it is not. Can you tell me how they are identical?

Comment: @DVK modified the question for you. Please re-open the question.

Comment: @JMFB - just to be clear, I voted my own opinion. Not Richard's (he merely alerted me to the possibility of a dupe). The reason it is duplicated is Richard's comment I upvoted - Slytherincess' answer exaustively enumerates **all** powers that Harry obtained from the fragment, and exta power for spells wasn't one.

Comment: @JMFB - Sorry, the edit now makes it the dupe [of the other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/were-there-any-canon-examples-of-harry-being-an-innately-powerful-wizard) ("Was Harry a powerful wizard") that basically is answered in a circle-reference answer of "Yes he was, **because he cast a Patronus**"

Comment: @DVK I can't believe you would allow that question to stand. If I posed a question like that it would be knocked down as too general a question leading to opinion based answers. That question gives it's own answer way more than any of mine has, which also leads me to wonder why you or richard didn't edit out all of those example (had no quotes or proof I might add). It's also a pretty basic question and the answers were mostly incorrect, unless one hasn't read the series or had the ability to deduce properly. So I can't ask this specific question bc it might be inside that general one?