# Was the Sorting Hat confused about Harry due to Voldemort's soul?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Harry**: Not Slytherin. Not Slytherin.
>
> **Sorting Hat**: Not Slytherin, eh? Are you sure? You could be great, you know. It's all here in your head. And Slytherin will help you on the way to greatness, there's no doubt about that. No?

According to Sorting Hat, Harry was best suited for Slytherin. Was this a confusion came because of Voldemort's soul part in Harry? Or, did Harry originally had attributes to be a great Slytherin?

Comment: Duplicate as mentioned, because [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10988/19561) addresses this question specifically.